# Mono or .NET Serialport frequent reads result in high cpu

Tags: c#, mono, serial-port, cpu

I'm developing an app that polls RS232 to I2C converter, to which i have an i2c device connected, that has to be polled in realtime, meaning constantly :D As soon as response comes i reissue the command again...

my code:

```
        lock (_locker)
        {
            try
            {

                _serialPort.DiscardInBuffer();
                _serialPort.Write(sendArray, 0, sendArray.Length);
                _serialPort.ReadFixed(headerArray, headerArray.Length);
                returnOperation = (DeviceOperation)((int)headerArray[1] << 8 | (int)headerArray[3]);
                DataToReceive = headerArray[5] * 256 + headerArray[6];
                if (DataToReceive != 0)
                {
                    _serialPort.ReadFixed(recvArray, DataToReceive);
                }
                _serialPort.ReadFixed(EOT, 1); //EOT
            }
            catch (Exception e )
            {
                Logger.Log(Level.Error, _name, "Fauled to execute command.", e);
                return false;                    
            }
        }
```

where ReadFixed is an extension:

```
    public static void ReadFixed(this SerialPort port, byte[] buffer, int count)
    {
        int offset = 0;
        while (count != offset)
            offset += port.Read(buffer, offset, count - offset);

        if (count != offset)
            throw new TimeoutException("ReadFixed did not receive specified bytes in time!");
    }
```

This piece of code results in around 40 - 60 % CPU usage on a dual core processor. I used ANTS profiler and it says that the function READFIXED is hot, and the cpu consumed inside is really high.

Any idea what is wrong? why such cpu usage ? Am I doing something wrong ?

Thank you for your replies!

Comment: Add a small `Thread.Sleep`. It will use less CPU and won't hurt the serial performance much.

Comment: That's why SerialPort has the DataReceived event.  So you don't have to poll.

Comment: DataReceived does not work in mono/Linux... thats why poll. I also tried putting 5 ms sleep and the cpu load dropped to 20-35%... On C++ i don't remember having cpu problems with high frequent serial calls

Comment: @Lonko - C++ is more effective at things which is the reason its used.  As already pointed out try DataRecieved see if the cpu usage drops.  You could also poll the serial port using C++ if you really wanted.

Comment: @Ramhound cannot use Datareceived event handler because it is not implemented in mono/linux ;) otherwise i would :P

Comment: DataReceived event would not help here really. With infinite timeout (which is the default, so if you've changed it, consider increasing) calls to Read are blocking, so they'll wait until data on serial port is available. The polling here takes place on a different level (I2C device) and can't be eliminated using DataReceived. Above suggested small sleep would probably be best option here, do some experiments with its value.

Comment: @konrad.kruczynski the only option was indeed having a small sleep ranging from 10 - 20 ms. I did not try to make a c++ dll only for serial reads, would that help and then invoke it ? Would c++ be here more helpfull?

Comment: @Lonko: IMO it won't be helpful. If you analyse the source code, you'll see that SerialPort class methods simply call internal routines written in C. You can find their source code here: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/support/serial.c What you can change, is the configuration of the serial port and method used to read it - which is quite easy with Mono.Unix and UnixStream. IMO, however, the small sleep approach is good enough. Overall, considering your main loop, the faster (i.e. less waiting) I/O you have, the more CPU for the rest of the loop will be eaten ;)

Answer (score 3):

By default `serialport.Read()` will immediately return, regardless if bytes have been received or not. If you set`serialport.Timeout = 2000`, the thread will block until bytes are available or it times out after 2 s. This will result in low CPU usage, and will give better responsiveness than a `Thread.Sleep`.

Be aware that this will block your thread. If this is an issue, do all your reading in a `BackgroundWorker` thread. You can use signalling, for example by using `AutoResetEvent`, to efficiently communicate with your foreground thread.