# Checking SerialPort.BytesToRead vs using TimeoutException in a read loop?

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port, timeoutexception

I have a .NET C# class which uses `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort` for serial port communication. It includes a thread which continuously read the serial port in a loop.

I have always thought that using Exceptions as part of normal program flow was bad, but searching the web I see many examples using blocking Read and `TimeoutException` to wait for incoming data, like this:

```
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        serialPort.Read(buffer, offset, count);
        /* Processing code here */
    }
    catch (TimeoutException)
    { }
}
```

Wouldn't it be better to check `SerialPort.BytesToRead()` before issuing the `Read`, like in this example:

```
while (true)
{
    if (serialPort.BytesToRead() <= 0)
    {
        /* Wait for event signal or similar. */
    }

    serialPort.Read(buffer, offset, count);
    ProcessData();
}
```

Comment: There is an inherent overhead associated with the exception, populating properties, creating stack trace, etc, so using exceptions in normal program flow is generally a bad idea.

Comment: It's ok to use exceptions and suppress them. The timeout exception because you don't have data is ok.

The first approach with a high timeout like 2 seconds, make your thread wait almost without using CPU.

The second approach forces you to use an spinlock that uses 100% CPU. Except you use a windows only flag process using the DataReceived event. But it will over complicate and also use much more CPU.
Look [User3279361 answer]:
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172996/mono-or-net-serialport-frequent-reads-result-in-high-cpu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second approach is definitely better. *Exceptions* should not be used to control *normal* program flow.

Additionally, the first approach will really clutter your debugging experience, especially if you set your IDE to break on every thrown exception.

Comment: Just to clarify, you meant the _first_ approach will really clutter your debugging experience, right?

Comment: I dont agree. Sometimes you will get 'serialPort.BytesToRead()== 0' but not everything is yet received. That's why the timeout is considered as the max time to wait for an answer, after which the complete payload is supposed delivered.

Comment: @Naxto the question is about using BytesToRead as a means to know when to _start_ reading so that you don't continuously try reading and get timeout exceptions while waiting for a message to arrive. It's purpose is _not_ to know that the whole message has been received.

Answer (score -1):

Do not read the port, you have a special function:

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
     int n = serialPort1.BytesToRead;
     ...
}
```